# Containerized flask app does not load if port is Changed

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have created a simple flask app that is running on a this is the skeleton o the flask app, which by default runs at port 5000:

```
# Create the application instance
app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir="./")

# read the swagger.yml file to configure the endpoints
app.add_api("swagger.yml")




# Create a URL route in our application for "/"
@app.route("/")
def home():
    """
    This function just responds to the browser URL
    localhost:5000/

    :return:        the rendered template "home.html"
    """
    return render_template("home.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In the Dockerfile I'm exposing the same port:

```
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 5000
```

Then I run the container as:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 my_app:latest
```

and once the container is up, I'm able to acces to app at:

```
http://localhost:5000
```

Now, I'm trying to change to port 5100, for that I'm changing:

a) In the Dockerfile:

```
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 5100
...
```

b) When I run the container:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5100:5100 my_app:latest
```

But when I try to visit: http://localhost:5100/

The app is not running there

When I do **Docker ps**  this is shown:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I tried changing the flask app:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5100)
```

Still not working, this is the screenshot from docker ps:

[image]

Not sure if the error is because still says 5000: at the begining:

```
5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5100->5100/tcp   romantic_fermi
```

This is what I get from docker logs...

```
 * Serving Flask app "server" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: It's because you need to change `app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)`, otherwise, it defaults to `127.0.0.1:5000` which isn't reachable externally

Comment: Furthermore, the `EXPOSE` in your dockerfile isn't necessary if you are explicitly exposing the port in the `docker run` command

Comment: @C.Nivs Thanks, one I'll try that. You meant port=5100 right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I put `host=5001`

Comment: @C.Nivs You put: app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5001) I'm asking for 5100, it should be 5100 right?

Comment: Ah right, yep, missed it twice!

Comment: @C.Nivs tried it, still not working. I updated the question

Comment: Looks like your image still has the old python code (I mean after the update to app.run()... Can you verify that your image has to latest python code..?

Comment: @SamDaniel How can I see that?

Comment: ```docker run -it my_app:latest bash``` and inside the shell cat the file.

Comment: @SamDaniel You are right, it has the old version. How can that happend? I'm building the image after each change. But that one file in the image is not changing

Comment: hard to say.. Perhpas you's latest is not tagged to the latest build you built? or build has failed and it slipped your notice,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could technically change the default port assigned to the `Flask` object, but it's simpler to just change the docker mapping.

When you run a command like this:

```sh
$ docker run -d -p 5100:5100 my_app:latest
```

You are saying that you want to forward a port from inside the container (on the right) to your host machine (on the left).

```
# Left side is your host machine
# Right side is inside of the container
5100:5100
```

So you could update your `run` to map to `5000` inside of the container:

```sh
$ docker run -d -p 5100:5000 my_app:latest
```

Then you'll be able to access via http://localhost:5100

---

PS: If you haven't used `docker-compose` before, I would highly recommend setting it up after you've worked through this issue. It'll make your life easier in general.

Comment: The problem is, the python app is still listening to 5000,,

Comment: That's fine. Leave the app listening at 5000 and update the docker command to point to port 5000 instead of 5100.

Comment: Perhaps he wants to know why doesn't his code work, provided everything looked right.

Comment: His code was fine and was working as expected. His docker command was incorrect and needs to be updated. No code changes needed.

Comment: After ```app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5100)``` the app was still listening to 5000. His image does not have the latest code, As per his comments.

Comment: Ya, he should just put it back to how he originally had it.

Answer (score 2):

On your .py script ou need to set 5100 port with:

```
app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', port=5100)
```

Everything else you did is correct!

If still your python are listening on port 5000, probably it's the old version.